# Tomcat5 SSL not working

Tags: ssl, https, windows-server-2008-r2, keystore, tomcat5

I am working on a Windows 2008 Server and have successfully set up a webapp on Tomcat v5.5.  I can access the app via http, but not via https.

In my Tomcat server.xml, I have defined the https connector as follows:

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" 
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true" 
           SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keyAlias="server" keystoreFile="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/<keystore>.jks" 
           keypass="<keypass>" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

I've also verified that the keystore file exists and that I can view the certificate contained within using the specified keypass.  Is there anything else I'm missing?  I did NOT create the keystore file locally, but rather copied it from another system.  Do I need to "install" it somehow?  Lastly, does IIS have to be installed/configured to access Tomcat via https locally?

I also cannot access Tomcat in general via https in the browser:

```
https://localhost/
```

Accessing Tomcat via http works fine:

```
http://localhost/
```

Comment: Look in the logs and maybe there will be an error?

Comment: No errors as far as I can see.  I've searched through all the logs.  When I try connecting it just spins for a while, then finally says 'This page can't be displayed' in IE (not by choice)

Comment: Is there a particular log file I should be looking at?

Comment: try catalina.out in the tomcat/logs directory

Comment: No dice.  The file, catalina.2013-11-21, doesn't have any statements indicating an attempt to connect to it.  Should I add more logging?

Comment: When you did `http://localhost/` did the tomcat web page appear?

Comment: Yes, when I ran `http://localhost/` it did, but not when I ran `https://localhost/`

Answer (score 0):

My server.xml looks like (and works)

```
   <Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="conf/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="blah123"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

so your file
with `<keystore>.jks`
looks wrong - no angle brackets eh.

Comment: I put in the brackets simply to indicate that it's a file.  The actual filename does not contain any unusual characters

Comment: I think the problem may be that I'm reusing a certificate from a different machine.

Comment: well maybe you should try doing it from the same machine then.